# Embryo stem cells and the concept of "person"

Tags: epistemology, social-ethics, bioethics

I have to do a very good, clear, and simple presentation on embryo stem cells **so that everyone can understand**. I have done the part of biology regarding these cells but I have to do the part that regards philosophy and bioethics. In many countries embryo stem cell medical application have provoked large discussions. **Can we consider the embryo a person? Does it have a dignity?** These are the questions that generate discussion. I want to present the philosophical meaning of the person. Can you suggest to me one very important author that gave a very considerable and deep concept of the person? (I want to focus on one fundamental author, avoiding a boring presentation) I thought about Mounier or Scheler but I really don't know. I need your help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Related SEP entry: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/stem-cells/#WheDoeHumBeiBegExi

Answer (score 4):

There is no one philosophical position on the meaning of "person". There are at least three important camps on personhood: *animalists* think that something is a person if and only if it is a human being, *Lockeans* think that something is a person if and only if it is the subject of the right kind of mental states (Lockeans disagree about exactly which state is taken to be important), and *Lynn Rudder Baker* holds a view called constitutionalism, which is supposed to be a middle ground. According to her something is a person if it has the right psychological states (she thinks having "first-personal awareness" is the important state) AND it is constituted by a body of the right kind.

Do a little more research on the topic and when you have more specific questions, come back and we'll see if we can help more.